# Toolchain binaries cannot be found

Tags: command-line, arm, cross-compilation

Trying to build recent version of u-boot bootloader for my mini2440 ARM board I managed to download a toolchain package from codesourcery and extract it to following path:
`/usr/local/arm-2008q3/`

I also exported following values for current session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/arm-2008q3/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

When I run `make` I get a following output and I cant figure out why:

```
make: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
for dir in tools examples api_examples ; do make -C $dir _depend ; done
make[1]: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `_depend'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/tools'
make[1]: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: Command not found
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/deth/uboot/mini2440/examples'
/bin/sh: 1: arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
```

I double checked everything and binaries indeed reside in mentioned folder but...
Please explain where I'm wrong.

Comment: Check that the binaries are marked as executable, and that permissions are 0755.

Comment: yep, I gave full permissions to those

Comment: the weird point is that it fails with "file not found" when I execute it directly, either with my user or sudo :\

Comment: Can you run `ldd` on the file? I have a possible cause.

Comment: not a dynamic executable

Comment: Interesting. Not what I was expecting, but OK, I suppose.

Comment: In fact, after sitting and trying everything I could possibly try given my current knowledge (I'm quite a seasoned developer in Win environment but rather newbie in Linux), it all boils down to simple fact. I can perfectly invoke the arm-none-eabi-gcc which is installed in /usr/bin folder but get "No such file or directory" while doing /usr/local/arm-2014.05/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after almost three days of headbanging into the wall I managed to solve this. To be honest I might have never solved it if occasionally hadn't installed the COdesourcery toolchain with executable installer which they also provide. After doing that the manually unpacked version started to execute! This of course led to a conclusion that there were libraries missing. I tried to reproduce the problem on separate virtual machine and voila, here are couple of words that solved the whole issue:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Hope this will help someone, and thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a few more variables.  Below is something which works for me with the toolchain installed in my home directory (yours is different, just change the MY_ARM_BASE). I don't do much cross compiling, so I put the necessary variables into a file, (I called mine "myconfig") and run it with the dot command to put it into my environment (so the  execute permission is not even needed).

```
.  myconfig
```

Now the makefile I was using was NOT from the supplier of the toolchain, so I did go into the toolchain's bin directory, and added links to the executables with short names e.g.:

```
ln -s arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ g++
```

I then added the CXX definition to the toolchain variables  to let the makefile run.

=== Put into a file, for convenience ===

```
MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######
CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc
CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```

Comment: What kind of file should it be? .sh script?